# Laravel One-To-Many but data must inside Model::all() output

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I'm building a application that contains information about trees. Trees has belongs to many zones. So for solution I make two datatables called Trees and TreeZones they has primary and foreign keys thats match. I used "hasMany" and "belongsTo" operators to make a relationship between these two. Everythings works fine actually but there is one problem. The application has REST API controllers. In index function I'm pulling all tree data. And I need zones too. I solved this like this;

```
/**
    public function index()
    {
        $trees = Tree::all();

        foreach($trees as $key => $tree){
            
            $treeData = Tree::find($tree->id);
            
            foreach($treeData->zones as $zone)
            {
                $trees[$key]['zones'];
            }
        }

       return ['data'=>$trees];
    }
```

Output is like this;

```
 {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Kavak Ağacı",
            "min": "-45.6",
            "max": "-42.8",
            "url": "https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/255/713/198/poplar-trees-near-lake-wallpaper-preview.jpg",
            "zones": [
                {
                    "zone": "2a"
                },
                {
                    "zone": "4b"
                }
            ]
        },
        .
        .
        .
}
```

But I want it to looks like this.

```
 {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Kavak Ağacı",
            "min": "-45.6",
            "max": "-42.8",
            "url": "https://p4.wallpaperbetter.com/wallpaper/255/713/198/poplar-trees-near-lake-wallpaper-preview.jpg",
            "zones": [
               "2a",
               "4b",
               "5c"
            ]
        },
        .
        .
        .
}
```

How can I solve this with clean solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can user `transform()` method and use **Eager loading** rather than using DB call inside foreach loop.
Try this

```
public function index()
{
    $trees = Tree::with(['zones'])->get();

    $trees->transform(function($tree, $key) {
        foreach ($tree->zones as $zoneKey => $zone) {
            $trees["zones"][$zoneKey] =  $zone->name //if you have name column
        }
        return $trees;
    })
    
   return ['data'=>$trees];
}
```